# concurrency in database opener

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I have no idea how to do proper concurrent operations, so I just tried to adjust my code.
And totally lost in concurrency in constructor and concurrency with static, final fields...

```
public static class Connection {
        private final CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper mHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
        private String mUserId;
        private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter;

        public Connection(Context context, String userId) {
            mHelper =  CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper.getInstance(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            mOpenCounter = mHelper.mOpenCounter;
            mUserId = userId;
        }

        public void open() throws SQLException {
            // open database in reading/writing mode
            int value = mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet();
             if(value == 1 || mDatabase==null || mUserId ==null) {
                    // Opening new database
                 Log.v("tugce","open new customer db");

                 mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                }

        };

        public void close() {
            int value = mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet();
             if(value == 0) {
                    // Closing database
                 if (mDatabase != null) {
                        try {
                             Log.v("tugce","close customer db");
                            mDatabase.close();
                            mDatabase = null;
                            mUserId = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
        }
```

//my openhelper class

```
public class CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    public static CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper mInstance;

    public static synchronized CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper getInstance(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version);
        }
        return mInstance;
      }

    private CustomerDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
```

This is how I am using in threads:

```
class MyGetPlanedCallList extends
            AsyncTask<Object, Object, List<MyPlannedCallListItem>> {
        CustomerDatabase.Connection mDbCon = new CustomerDatabase.Connection(InstanceActivity.this, mUserId);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mDbCon.open();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<MyPlannedCallListItem> doInBackground(Object... params) {
            mDbCon.doSomeStuff();
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MyPlannedCallListItem> result) {
            mDbCon.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            if (mDbCon != null)
                mDbCon.close();
        }
    }
```

What I want is, exactly same db shouldn't be closed if some other instance is working on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To effectively solve this you will have to consider couple of things ,some of which I have listed  below: 1) Why do you need multiple connections? 2) Are you considering connection per thread approach or a pool of connections would be fine. 3) What's the expected application DB hit rate (I guess it's a mobile app ) If the DB hits are very low can't you have a single connection instance which is shared across multiple requests.

Comment: @AnupamSaini thanks for your comment I edited the sample usage, actually what I want is exactly one database connection is open at same time and used by all threads, but that connection should be closed only if all threads using that connection is finished running. I have tried to wrap this solution(https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/dmytrodanylyk/blob/gh-pages/articles/Concurrent%20Database%20Access.md) in one more class in my project, but I don't know what is wrong in my implementation